# Display bar plot for two groups separately in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I would like to do the horizontal bar plot in R for the 'Yes' and 'No' columns separated by a vertical line at zero:

```
dat <- matrix(c(10,8, 20, 6,0, 25), nrow=3, dimnames=list(c("A", "B", "C"), 
                                                          c("Yes", "No")  ))
```

something like:

[image: sample figure]

where blue is for the 'Yes' and yellow for the 'No' group. Could you please help me to do this in R?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

[image]

```
dat <- data.frame(dat)
barplot(dat$Yes,horiz=T, xlim=c(-max(dat$No),max(dat$Yes)), col="lightgreen")
barplot(-dat$No,horiz=T, add=T, col="lightblue")
```

Same thing with `ggplot`

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
gg <- cbind(id=rownames(dat),dat)
ggplot(gg, aes(x=id))+
  geom_bar(aes(y=Yes, fill="Yes"), stat="identity")+
  geom_bar(aes(y=-No, fill="No"),  stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_manual("Response",values=c(Yes="lightgreen",No="lightblue"))+
  labs(y="value")+coord_flip()
```